# Propositional logic expression

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$(\lnot p \lor q) \land \lnot[(p\lor \lnot q)\Rightarrow (p\lor q)]$ 
is equivalent to $\lnot (p\lor q)$

Ok so I'm supposed to simplify the expression to get the other one, but I'm stuck.
Currently I'm with this:
$$(\lnot p \lor q) \land \lnot[(\lnot p\land q)\lor (p\lor q)]$$

I don't know how to solve what's between $[{}\cdot{}]$. If I had 2 $\land$ it would be easy.
Can someone explain how I can surpass this? Thank you

Comment: Apply $\neg$ to what is inside $[-]$, then distribute $\wedge$

Comment: Tip: $\neg [A\to B] ~\equiv~\neg[\neg A\vee B]~\equiv~ [A\wedge\neg B]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The attempts are correct so far, now see if we can find somewhere to apply Absorption law.

**Answer:**

\begin{align}
&(\lnot p \lor q) \land \lnot[(\lnot p\land q)\lor (p\lor q)]\\
\equiv&(\lnot p \lor q) \land \lnot[((\lnot p\land q)\lor q) \lor p]\tag*{Reordering}\\
\equiv&(\lnot p \lor q) \land \lnot(q \lor p)\tag*{Absorption law}\\
\equiv&(\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \land \lnot p)\tag*{De Morgan's law}\\
\equiv&((\lnot p \lor q) \land \lnot p) \land \lnot q)\tag*{Reordering}\\
\equiv&\lnot p \land \lnot q\tag*{Absorption law}\\
\equiv&\lnot (p \lor q)\tag*{De Morgan's law}\\
\end{align}